# Osm2pgsql data dump in specific schema not working

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, planet, pbf

While using osm2pgsql 1.6 i am trying to dump PBF into specific schema of postgres DB using following commands using docker. (i am setting database properties in docker env)

docker run -v /mnt/ne-blobs/:/mnt/ne-blobs/ --env PGHOST=$PGHOST --env PGPORT=$PGPORT --env PGUSER=$PGUSER --env PGDATABASE=$PGDATABASE --env PGPASSWORD=$PGPASSWORD osm2pgsql:1.6.0 **osm2pgsql -c -E 4326 --hstore --slim -C 8000 --output-pgsql-schema=$schema_name -r pbf /path/to/pbf.**

I am creating schema before executing this command but i see that only
planet_osm_line
planet_osm_point
planet_osm_polygon
planet_osm_roads

are getting created in my mentioned schema

but core tables like
Planet_osm_nodes
planet_osm_rels
planet_osm_ways

are getting created in public schema. Is there anything i am doing wrong with the command? i want to create all 7 tables in one schema which is execution specific.

Answer (score 1):

You should use also these Middle Options https://osm2pgsql.org/doc/man/version-1-6-0.html in your command:

> **--tablespace-slim-data**=TABLESPC Store the slim mode tables in the given tablespace.
>
> **--tablespace-slim-index**=TABLESPC Store the indexes of the slim mode tables in the given tablespace.